# Classifying space of non-connected Lie groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, classifying-spaces

Let $G$ be a Lie group and $G_1$ the connected component of the identity. Is there anything we can say about the classifying groups $BG$ and $B(G_1)$?
I suspect no since we could take a discrete group and $B(G_0)$ will be in general very different to $BG$. But possibly something like: the free parts of the homology groups of $BG$ and $B(G_1)$ are the same holds.

Comment: There is a fibration $B(G_1) \rightarrow BG \rightarrow B(G/G_1)$ which one can apply the Serre spectral sequence to.

Comment: Is there anything obvious we can say in general given from this spectral sequence or is this just useful in specific calculations

Comment: To me the entire theory of group homology is about calculations so I would say it is generally useful.